# Landscape setting in Chrome is not available when using ReactToPrint

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome

Using this https://github.com/gregnb/react-to-print

When printing, I don't have the orientation property in Chrome print dialog.

[image]

As you can see, I have a table with many columns. Landscape orientation would be preferred.

On what condition is Chrome hiding this feature? Is some html-element triggering this?

Comment: Did you find any use of my answer? If it didn't work for you, please add some more details like an endpoint URL to check or a sample source code.

Comment: @ChristosLytras Sorry I've not had time to try it yet. I'll try it at beginning of next week.

Answer (score 9):

This happens because there is a CSS `@page` with `size` declaration somewhere in your code. And if there is a specific size defined, like for example `portrait` or `A4 portrait`, then Chrome (*and most likely other browsers*) will hide the *Orientation* option.

If you have multiple CSS installed and you're not sure from where that CSS declaration may come, then you can create your CSS `@page` rule with `size: auto` and even make it `!important`.

```css
@page {
  size: auto;
}
```

or using `!important` if you can't override the declaration:

```css
@page {
  size: auto !important;
}
```

Then print dialog will have the *Orientation* dropdown option.